# Can't connect to postgres docker container (localhost)

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have downloaded a docker image from docker hub to get a container with postgres, with the following command:

`docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name postgres-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres postgres`

But somehow I can't connect to it, I ran `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -W` followed by the default password (postgres) and I get the error:

`psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Note that the container is running correctly (Green status in dashboard, says RUNNING on PORT:5432)..

Any idea why I get this error? I am very new to docker and I'm getting lost easily, I haven't found answers to my problem but I might be wording it incorrectly.

EDIT: I can run this command successfully from the bash of the container after running `docker exec -it postgres-docker bash`. Why is it working from inside the container but not from outside if the port is the same on the container and the host? Windows host if it matters

Comment: stupid question maybe but you are running the container on your local machine/laptop I suppose? If you are using Docker Machine, can you try to connect to 192.168.99.100:PORT or find out the correct IP?

Comment: as a first step to analyze this I'd run the postgres server on a different port on the local machine, so that a problem with other instances on the same box can be ruled out. Try this: docker run -d -p 9999:5432 --name postgres-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres postgres and then psql -h localhost -p 9999 -U postgres -W. Does this give the same result?